# rsync: --backup-dir behaviour on full disk?

Tags: rsync, backup

I have a question regarding **rsync** and its **--backup-dir** option, since I found no useful info in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) regarding its behaviour on a full disk.

If I have for example 3 disks, *A* as source, *B* as destination and *C* specified as backup-dir among others for deleted files, may I expect rsync to stop the operation if **backup directory** *C* **is full**? And assuming it actually stops, would there be a way to detect programmatically it stopped because of this very reason?
The exit codes only seem to cover more general errors.